# Cannot access grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) in offline mode

Tags: grails

This morning I cloned new project and when I do :

```
refresh dependencies
```

In order to download the the plugins specified under *buildConfig* I am getting this error:

```
Cannot access grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) in offline mode
```

full stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/G9UEMvwT

*What could be the possible reasons for the error?*

Thanks,

Comment: Did you add `--offline` to the command?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith no , should I?

Comment: No, just wondering why you're seeing a message saying you're offline. Do you need to configure a proxy?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith sorry I was having this line `grails.offline.mode=true` n my `buildConifg` so changed it to `grails.offline.mode=false`. The project was not mine and I did not know there was such option in grails.

Comment: Either did I :)  Does it work now?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith yeah, it is downloading the plugins

Answer (score 0):

I was having this line:

```
 grails.offline.mode=true
```

in my **buildConifg** so changed it to:

```
 grails.offline.mode=false
```

Detail : see *Offline Mode* section on http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/conf.html